# Can Obfuscar obfuscate .NET 4.6.x, WPF, .NET Standard Libraries?

Tags: obfuscation, obfuscar

I have a VS2017 solution that includes projects targeting .NET 4.6.1, using WPF and .NET Standard Libraries. I am wondering if I can use Obfuscar to obfuscate the exe and dll files.

Any insights are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why cannot you test?